# Succulent (aloe?) with strange growth coming from the stem

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, succulents

I inherited a mystery house plant that I assumed was some type of aloe. Honestly I wasn't too worried about it (it seemed happy and pretty enough) until it got these yellow growths where the leaves meet the stem. I've never seen it before and the rest of the plant seems to be business as usual.
Can anyone identify the problem and/or the plant?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Couple of queries - how long has it been in the same pot, and how much direct sunlight  does it receive?

Comment: Thank you for replying! It was repotted maybe 6mos ago as it needed a larger pot. And no direct sunlight. It's in a very sunny bathroom thanks to the skylight, but tucked away from direct light due to the angle of the roof.

Answer (score 1):

Those are roots! Most likely because you have it where the humidity is high. Great time to propagate if you want! ❤️

Answer (score 1):

I think your plant is an aloe of some variety - its growing rather haphazardly, probably because of the lack of direct daylight.

The brown things are adventitious roots, which may well be a signal that the plant  is not entirely happy with its growing conditions, and the roots will grow longer in an attempt to locate themselves in better conditions. They also do better in non transparent pots, just an ordinary pot with drainage holes  will do.

Care instructions here https://www.almanac.com/plant/aloe-vera but note that not all Aloes are Aloe vera - I am not sure which yours is because it's so leggy, so don't use the juice from cut leaves if you are not sure of the variety.