# Can someone help me identify what is growing out of my Aloe plant?

Tags: identification, plant-health

[image]My wife asked me to take this Aloe plant into my office since it was doing poorly in our home. It has since been thriving in the office but I noticed this week something bursting from the core of the plant. Any idea what this is?

Comment: Those are adventitious roots - and you can find more details in this [Q/A](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/52138/7456). I’m going to close this question as a duplicate (which is in fact good news, as it means you don’t have to wait for the community to answer, but can directly use the existing answers.)